# How do I get to the recipe log?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

If I make a new recipe in Breath of the Wild, is it recorded anywhere? If so, how do I view the recipes I've discovered. I thought the help text indicated something like this when I first made something, however; I don't remember what it says or how to find my recipes.

Comment: Not sure there is an in-game log of them, but there's an entire wiki page on them you can look at which includes what goes in it, hearts restored etc. http://orcz.com/Breath_of_the_Wild:_Recipes

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I'm not as interested in having a list of recipes as much as I'm interested in having a list of recipes that I've personally encountered.

Comment: Figured I would share my findings, didn't think it was exactly what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no "Recipe Log" in Breath of the Wild.

The closest you can get is by looking at a meal / elixir in your inventory, selecting it, and then selecting "Recipe" (instead of Eat / Drink, if you were consuming it).

This will tell you what ingredients were involved in its creation, even if you originally received the item as a reward (or were otherwise uninvolved in its manufacture).

So the "Recipe Log", as it were, is only as large as the number of cooked items you currently have on you.

Answer (score 10):

The other way to create a "Recipe Log". Is after you create something that you want to remember follow Sable Dreamer Answer's instructions

> The closest you can get is by looking at a meal / elixir in your inventory, selecting it, and then selecting "Recipe" (instead of Eat / Drink, if you were consuming it).

Then take a screenshot on the Wii U or the Switch. This allows me to to quickly cycle thru my screenshots to find a Recipe for something I made in the past and is sorta a improvised "Recipe Log".